# What's the difference between 'passwd' and 'chpasswd'?

Tags: linux, command-line

I read description of these command from a book, 
**passwd:**

> Changes the password for an existing user.

**chpasswd:**

> Reads a file of login name and password pairs, and updates the passwords.

It seems these command doing same jobs. Is there a difference between them?

EDIT:

I want to learn when we use them which file(s) change. Do they change same file or different file? If they change different file(s), what are they?

Comment: `/etc/password` contains user account information. `/etc/shadow` contains encrypted passwords.  I believe those are the only files that are relevant. You could change a password by manually editing those files, but it would be very awkward.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

From `man chpasswd`:

'This command is intended to be used in a large system environment where many accounts are created at a single time.'

`passwd` is (in my experience) normally used interactively for a single user.

Answer (score 8):

In a nutshell:

- `passwd` checks if the STDIN (file descriptor 0) is attached to the terminal, using `isatty(0)`. If not, `passwd` would bail out i.e. you can only work with `passwd` interactively
- `chpasswd`, on the other hand, is designed to read (username and) password from STDIN, and is called the batch mode (creates/updates multiple user credentials at once). It reads password(s) (in clear text by default), and username(s) from STDIN, given in the format `user_name:password`, with newline separating the entries

Answer (score 7):

See man pages for both of them:

> NAME
>
>   chpasswd - update passwords in batch mode
>
> SYNOPSIS
>
>   `chpasswd`
>   [options]
>
> DESCRIPTION
>
>   The
>   `chpasswd`
>   command reads a list of user name and password pairs from standard input and uses this information
>     to update a group of existing users. 
>     Each line is of the format:
>
> user_name:password

---

> NAME
>
>   passwd - change user password
>
> SYNOPSIS
>
>   `passwd`
>   [options] [LOGIN]
>
> DESCRIPTION
>
>   The
>   `passwd`
>   command changes passwords for user accounts. 
>     A normal user may only change the password for his/her own account,
>     while the superuser may change the password for any account.
>   `passwd`
>   also changes the account or associated password validity period.

Answer (score 1):

I found that although

```
echo user:password | chpasswd
```

works for some OSes, some such as debian9,10 will show an error `can not connect to /var/run/nscd/socket` since it uses `/etc/nsswitch.conf` to determine where it stores the password.

On the other side, the `passwd` command seems does not need interactive shell,

```
(echo user; echo password) | passwd
```

works for me both in physical host and container, for various OSes (ubuntu xenial-bionic, debian9-10, centos75-76, coreos1855-2135)