# While Loop over a File returning command not found

Tags: bash, shell-script

I'm Trying to create a simple shell script to loop through a file line by line and execute a command with each line as a variable.

Here is my Text File:

```
FakeAccount
FakeUser
```

Here Is My Shell Script:

```
#!/bin/bash

while IFS= read -r line; do
    "echo -e 'testpassword\ntestpassword' | passwd $line"
done < "User.txt"
```

The Output i get back seems to be what i want, the output says:

"line 4: echo -e 'testpasswd\ntestpasswd' | passwd FakeAccount: command not found"

"line 4: echo -e 'testpasswd\ntestpasswd' | passwd FakeUser: command not found"

But if i copy this exact string: echo -e 'testpasswd\ntestpasswd' | passwd FakeUser

the command works just fine so why is the shell script not executing the command and its saying command not found?

Comment: Why do you double quote the body of the loop? See also https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/345459/whats-the-difference-between-passwd-and-chpasswd

Comment: Beware anyone that has an account on this machine, can read the full command line and arguments of any command (so the password). (Unless you employ namespaces)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By enclosing the command and their arguments into double quotes, you're presenting the whole string as a single command which is, as the shell tells you, not found.

The shell needs to perform word splitting in order to find command lists, assignments, commands, and their parameters (see the opening sections of `man bash` to learn more).

Don't use double quotes on the whole pipeline, just quote the variable:

```
echo -e 'testpassword\ntestpassword' | passwd "$line"
```

Comment: Does your `passwd` read from standard input? ;-)

Comment: Yes it is looking for and can not find a command named `echo -e 'testpasswd\ntestpasswd' | passwd FakeAccount`

Comment: @Kusalananda: I haven't tried it, but the OP states *But if i copy this exact string... the command works just fine*

Answer (score 0):

You could do it even simpler as follows using `chpasswd`:

```
while read -r user; do printf "$user:%s" "some_secret_pass" | chpasswd ; done < User.txt
```

Or if you want to use `passwd` then you'd probably need to pass the `--stdin` flag. As far as I can see, this is supported in recent Fedora and Centos releases

Using `passwd`:

```
while read -r user; do printf %s\\n "some_secret_pass" | passwd --stdin "$user" ; done < User.txt
```